# Apache 2.4 configuration in production

Tags: apache

I have windows server 2016 in production . 
64 GB ram is installed .
Apache 2.4 web sever is installed .
About 1000 concurrent request hit on the server .
Performance is very slow.
What will be the apache configuration to improve performance?
Can any one help?

Comment: That's an awfully broad question. What technique are you using to talk to your webapp (reverse proxy? cgi? Or are you only hosting static content?).

Comment: No reverse proxy .No cgi. I am using apache web server only for balancing load between to Tomcat servers reside in two different machine.      No content is deployed in apache web  server  . I actually wanted to know what configuration parameters can improve   the web server performance.

Comment: I would say that load balancing is a special case of reverse proxy. Anyway, it is this scenario you will most likely want to optimize for a large number of async connections. Unless you do e.g. SSL termination you will not be CPU bound, thus you probably want a low thread count.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to post your conf to see if you are currently allowing for 1,000 concurrent connections.

Set ThreadsPerChild to something greater than 1,000, OR just set to 0 to completely remove the limit.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Default conf file are there .Only load balance related parameters are added. Please suggest which parameters need to be added or existing parameters  need to modified .please also suggest about approximate value of that parameters.

Comment: You probably don’t want a large number of threads in this scenario, as very little CPU work is done per connection. Better to go the async route.